# C# DLL return type in Python

Tags: c#, python, dll, return-type, dllexport

I have a simple problem, I have a basic C# CLL library that I created that I'm calling from Python2.7. I am using the following in C# to make my functions callable from outside:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
[DllExport("StartFrequency", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static double StartFrequency(double start)
{

    if (start != 0)// this is a set request
    {
        Console.WriteLine(start.ToString() + " Set Request");
        try
        {
            //driver.DriverOperation.QueryInstrumentStatus = false;
            driver.System.ClearErrors();
            driver.Frequency.Start = (double)start;
            driver.DriverOperation.QueryInstrumentStatus = true;
            return 1;
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot Write Start Value");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else// this is a get request
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Get Request");
        try
        {
            driver.System.ClearErrors();
            return driver.Frequency.Start;
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot Read Start Value");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that even if I try and return a different variable type such as string, float or bool, in Python it thinks the return type is always an Int.
Here is my python code:

```
driver = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(DLL)
a = driver.StopFrequency(c_double(600000000))
```

I also tried something like:

```
driver = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(DLL)
a = c_double(0.0)
a = driver.StopFrequency(c_double(600000000))
```

No matter what the return type of my C# function is, Python always assumes an Int.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Can somebody please help with this?